# I can't use \maketitle with tufte and lualatex

Tags: luatex, tufte

This short code compiles with pdflatex but not with lualatex. I can't use `\maketitle`

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-book}
\title{Functional Analysis
      \thanks{Thanks to Edward R.~Tufte for his inspiration.}}
\author{Andrew Tulloch}
\publisher{School of Mathematics and Statistics\\
           The University of Sydney}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: the class is loading soul package if used with luatex (not sure why yet)

Comment: hmm % If we're using pdfLaTeX v1.40+, use the letterspace package. 
% If we're using pdfLaTex < v1.40, use the soul package.
% If we're using XeLaTeX, use XeLaTeX letterspacing options.
% Otherwise fall back on the soul package.
   note it doesn't look for luatex at all....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that the `tufte-book` class is not yet able to work with LuaTeX > 0.85 which is a bit ridiculous, because it's been quite some time since that release.

The `tufte-book` class checks whether it can use the `letterspace` package by querying the value of `\pdftexversion`.  If that value is unset, it falls back to `soul`. Modern LuaTeX does not have the builtin `\pdftexversion` anymore (because it deviated quite substantially from pdfTeX over the years) and therefore the test fails and the incompatible `soul` is loaded.

Luckily there is a compatibility package, which emulates the old interfaces and allows old packages to work with new LuaTeX.  Just include it before `\documentclass`.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\meaning\@tufte@pdftexversion

\meaning\if@tufte@letterspace@pkg@prereqs
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

---

Without `\RequirePackage{luatex85}`

[image]

---

With `\RequirePackage{luatex85}`

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! because I was unable to compile `pgfornament` documentation.