# To have both Luatex85.sty and a correct \ifpdftex (through iftex.sty)

Tags: pdftex, luatex, tufte, luahbtex

Loading `luatex85.sty` makes `\ifpdftex` true, under Luatex or LuaHBTex. This is probably by design, however how can we revert back to the correct `\ifpdftex` after dealing with an old package that is still needs `luatex85.sty`?

In my case, I need to fool `tufte-latex` by using `luatex85.sty` as stated here: [I can't use \maketitle with tufte and lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533572/i-cant-use-maketitle-with-tufte-and-lualatex). However, my package which deals with bidi texts, need to distinguish between PDFTex, Xetex, and Luatex correctly. Is there anyway to have both solutions in the same package (or other workarounds)?

*MWE*

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{iftex}
\begin{document}
\ifluatex
This is Lua
\fi

\ifluahbtex
This is Lua HB
\fi

\ifpdftex
This is PDFTex
\fi

\ifxetex
This is xetex
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it in the question. Yes, I meant `ifpdftex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would really be better to just get the class fixed or patch it with a specific patch rather than using luatex85 which adds compatibility definitions for *everything*

However you can just add an extra test:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{iftex}
\begin{document}
\ifluatex
This is Lua
\fi

\ifluahbtex
This is Lua HB
\fi

\ifpdftex
\ifluatex
This is LuaTex
\else
This is PDFTex
\fi
\fi

\ifxetex
This is xetex
\fi

\end{document}
```

with lualatex you then get

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This code surely works, but it also shows that it is much better to find a fix or patch for `tufte-latex`. Tufte-latex has not been updated since 2015. That is a pity. I guess it is used frequently in the Tex community.